# Reference request: number of antichains of a partially ordered set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of all positive integers. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the set $$ P_n = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq a \leq b \leq n \} $$ and consider the partial order $\leq$ on $P_n$ given by $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ if $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$.

It is quite easy to show that the number of antichains of $(P_n,\leq)$ is $2^n$. But since this is such a simple example, the result is very likely long known. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone is aware of a reference. Thank you.

(Motivation for question: While investigating finitely generated varieties of monoids satisfying the equation $xyx=x^2y$, I found that they can be partitioned into intervals, where each is isomorphic to the lattice of antichains of some $(P_n,\leq)$ with the empty set treated as the greatest element.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me convert my comments into an answer.

Your poset $P=P_n$ can also be written as $P=J([2]\times[n-1])$, the lattice of order ideals of the product of a $2$-element chain and an $(n-1)$-element chain. It is an example of a *minuscule poset* (of Type B or D), which means it is intimately related to the combinatorics of Weyl groups, representations of Lie algebras, cohomology of flag varieties, et cetera. In particular, its collection of antichains, or equivalently order ideals, has been heavily investigated in work of Stanley, Proctor, Stembridge and others. More generally, there is a beautiful enumerative theory for the $P$-partitions of all minuscule posets, including this one.

For your poset $P$ in particular, see Section 5 of Stanley's "Weyl groups, ..." paper cited below, where its lattice of order ideals is denoted $M(n)=J(P)$. The elements of $M(n)$, which are in bijection with antichains of your poset $P$, are identified with subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, so the fact that there are $2^n$ of them is clear; see pg. 177 of the paper (which is available on Stanley's website: [https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf)). And see the papers of Proctor and Stembridge cited below for the more general theory of the combinatorics of minuscule posets. Specifically, your poset $P$ is discussed in Example 3.3 in the paper of Stembridge (available on his website at: [https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/papers/minuscule.ps.gz](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ejrs/papers/minuscule.ps.gz)), where the $2^n$ count is explained in terms of representations of $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$.

*Stanley, Richard P.*, [**Weyl groups, the hard Lefschetz theorem, and the Sperner property**](https://doi.org/10.1137/0601021), SIAM J. Algebraic Discrete Methods 1, 168-184 (1980). [ZBL0502.05004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0502.05004).

*Proctor, Robert A.*, [**Bruhat lattices, plane partition generating functions, and minuscule representations**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(84)80037-2), Eur. J. Comb. 5, 331-350 (1984). [ZBL0562.05003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0562.05003).

*Stembridge, John R.*, [**On minuscule representations, plane partitions and involutions in complex Lie groups**](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-94-07320-1), Duke Math. J. 73, No. 2, 469-490 (1994). [ZBL0805.22006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0805.22006).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and detailed explanation.